# Method in Delphi to set database connections to disconnected upon compile

Tags: delphi, database-connection, delphi-7, vcl

Is there a method or compiler directive or some way of assuring certain components, such as queries or database connections get set to active=false or disconnected when you run a build/compile?  Seems so often these are turned on by something else and you don't notice it until its too late.

My particular install is Delphi 7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Set Component Properties](http://www.gexperts.org/tour/setcomponentproperties.html) feature of GExperts is able to do that.

Answer (score 3):

i think the best option would be to subclass stock connection component and in your own one override `.Loaded` method like that

```
if not csDesigning in Self.ComponentState then
   if not Self.ActiveInDFM {new boolean published property} then
      if Self.Active then Self.Active := false;
inherited;
```

- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Classes.TComponentState
- http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Classes.TComponent.Loaded

By (ab)using Delphi Form Designer stupidness you can use it even without actually installing your new component into IDE Palette - just give it the same name as to the stock component class, then put your own method as last in the form's interface-uses list: thus in design-time you would have stock component and when compiling it would be transparently substituted with your own one.

Or you can sub-class it right above the very form declaration like (for another component):

```
type
   TPanel = class(ExtCtrls.TPanel)
   private
     ...

   TForm1 = class(TForm) ....
```

I guess this approach might be seen as analogue to aspect-oriented programming, using limitations of IDE in developer-benefitting way.

---

Another approach might be some script, that cleans .Active properties in DFM on save or before build, but this way is complex for

- i may be harder to integrate with stand-alone build severs (new script for each different CI framework tried)
- it would reset `Active` property for design-time as well. This is a proper thing to do, from rigorous point of view. Yet this might be not very convenient.

---

You may just use similar code in your Form's and DataModule's `.Loaded method` (you would have to override it instead connection's method then).

You can copy-paste the same code into every Form's Loaded method.

```
procedure TMyForm.Loaded; // override
var c: TComponent; i: integer;
begin
  try 
    for i := 0 to Self.ComponentsCount - 1 do begin
        c := Self.Components[i];
        if c is TCustomConnection then
           with TCustomConnection(c) do // Hate those redundant typecasts!
             if Connected then Connected := false;
        if c is TDataSet then
           with TDataSet(c) do // Delphi could took a lesson from Component Pascal
              if Active then Active := false;
        if c is ... // transactions, stored procedures, custom libriaries...
    end;
  finally
    inherited;
  end;
end;
```

This seems to be less sly way - thus most reliable. Yet that is a lot if copy-paste, and if you would later add some new component or library, that may ask for modifying copy-pasted code in all the forms.

You may centralize this code in some MyDBUtils unit into global procedure like `Disconnect(const owner: TComponent);` and then

```
procedure TMyForm.Loaded; // override
var c: TComponent; i: integer;
begin
  try 
    MyDBUtils.Disconnect(Self);
  finally
    inherited;
  end;
end;
```

This approach also has drawbacks though:

- This would make `MyDBUtils` unit tightly coupled with *all and every* the database-related libs and components you might use. For large inherited projects, consisting of different binary modules, historically based on different db-access libraries and in process of migration, thus pulling all the access libraries into every binary module.

  1. It can be overcome by ad hoc DI framework, but then the opposite can happen: you risk under-delivering, you may just forget to inject some library or component handler into the project that actually use it or got modified to use it.
- If your form would have some components, whose connectivity should NOT be reset (object arrays as datasets, in-memory tables, in-memory NexusDB or SQLite databases, etc), you'd have to come up with ad hoc non-obvious convention to opt them out.

Answer (score 1):

In my applications, I set my connection's `Tag` property to 1 at design time. In the `OnBeforeConnect` event, I check `Tag`, and if it is equal to 1, I abort the connection and set it to 0.

Comment: The trick with tag works fine. Just to clarify: connection can be aborted i.e. by clearing DatabaseName.